# Main aspect of circuit designing process

Tags: design

As a electrical and electronics engineering student I still do not understand what we actually mean by designing a circuit. Are we just trying to shape signals using components or make sure specified amount of current goes through a particular element or there is somehing much more deep in this? We learn about solving circuits but not designing them for some purposes. So what is the catch here?

Comment: That question is too broad for here, but mostly what I want is a certain functionality. Then think about what circuit will give me that functionality.

Comment: Functionality, then performance and performance against environmental conditions plus user interface requirements. Think about a power audio amplifier and list what criteria need to be met to design a good one.

Comment: The first step would be to know what you want your circuit is supposed to do. In the real world you don't design a circuit just because; you design a circuit to do something.

Comment: Something to do with meeting a set of design criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very thoughtful statement and reflects my own experience going through a EE degree.

Circuit analysis ("solving circuit problems") is the foundation on which circuit design/synthesis is built upon.  You can't really build something if you can't analyze it. (eg. you can't build a car if you can't diagnose simple car problems or list the different parts inside a car).

A lot of undergraduate work is learning the fundamental building blocks and theory of modern circuits.  Amplifiers, digital logic, filter design, board design, antenna design, wave propagation, etc.  You might not necessarily use all of it in your career, but you at least know the core components of modern circuits and are better equipped to modify an existing design when you encounter it, or design something better.

It's unfortunate that all this information comes piecemeal at university.  You don't see the big picture until you're a junior or senior.  At least, that's how it was for me.  Good luck in your studies-- don't feel bad if you don't see how it all comes together right now.  I've been there myself.

Answer (score 1):

I teach students electronics, and my goal has always been to allow you guys to design your own circuits. To me, *designing* fundamentally means being able to *use* anything *at your disposal* to come up with a solution to a problem. The problems are often obvious, but the solutions can almost invariably take many different forms: it is, in fact, closer to an **art**. But how do you *teach* an art?

I believe the best and most common ways are by the example of "masters" (to further draw on the analogy with art) and by exercise. You analyze great works, and you try to assimilate it in your own work by practicing. You learn and perfect basic techniques with the brush and paint to be able to express yourself on a canvas.

And this is pretty much what you're doing now. Every circuit you solve is an example that shows you how it can be done for you to assimilate and make your own. The equations and laws that govern electronics are the tools that you can use to express your idea in the form of a solution to a problem.